# reading a single contact from the SQLite database to new class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Oke so I have the next code in my DataBaseHandler

```
    // Getting single contact
    Database getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MOVIES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
    ,KEY_SUM,KEY_ACT,KEY_TRAILER,KEY_PREVIEW,KEY_DIR,KEY_WRI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Database contact = new Database(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
    cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),
cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7));

return contact;
    }
```

I need to get all the information from a certain ID. The ID depends on the number I send back. But when I try to call for the database in my class, it doesn't seem to work.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            // for this example i want to read out ID 15 in my database
    db.getContact(15);

}
```

When I read the content of `db.getContact(15);` I get back be.artesis.findmymovie.Database@436884e0, so it's not empty

```
// getting movie_director
            public String getMD(){
                return this._movie_director;
            }

            // setting movie_director
            public void setMD(String movie_director){   
                this._movie_director = movie_director;
            }
```

My Question is, now that I got this Contact, how can I use the information inside the ID?
I tried using the next methods and call for `db.getMD()`, but it doesn't work

Comment: why is getContact returning a database?

Comment: what is the problem? the getContact method returns a Database object but you do nothing with it.

Comment: found the answer myself, forgot to put db.getContact instead of getContact. -_- so stupid

Comment: Rotem, how can I now use this Database object? I have no idea how to call a specific field

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to work? But what's the content you get while calling getContact(15)? An NPE?

Comment: Wait until have enough rep(50) to comment please. Don't make comments as answers until you can.

Comment: It says it is undefined for the type info, and that I should make a method, but I don't know how that would help

Comment: be.artesis.findmymovie.Database@436884e0 is what I get back